# Host Multiple Sites on Apache with same IP and Port

Tags: ubuntu, web, apache2, virtualhost

Trying to host multiple sites from the same Ubuntu Apache box. Same IP and Same Port. The differentiation being the host header or domain address. I could do this easy with IIS but I'd like to move to Apache.

Right now with this code, every time I do a test with these URL's. I get pointed to the 1st URL even if I try a different URL. (I assume because it's the 1st Port 80 website). Everything works fine locally if your on the desktop of the Ubuntu server but not if your on a local desktop or internet. (These are my lab domain names.)

My www.conf file that sits in /etc/apache2/sites-available. The same conf file shows in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/dizydiz

ServerName dizydiz.com
ServerAlias www.dizydiz.com

</VirtualHost>

###

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/dizydiz2

ServerName dizzydiz.com
ServerAlias www.dizzydiz.com

</VirtualHost>

###

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/squeakerkiller

ServerName squeakerkiller.com
ServerAlias www.squeakerkiller.com

</VirtualHost>

###

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/dizydiz_legacy1

ServerName old.dizydiz.com

</VirtualHost>
```

I am using another Ubuntu box in front of this Web box as a ProxyPass box.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName dizydiz.com
     ServerAlias www.dizydiz.com
     ServerAlias kb.dizydiz.com
     ServerAlias old.dizydiz.com
     ServerAlias squeakerkiller.com
     ServerAlias www.squeakerkiller.com
     ServerAlias dizzdiz.com
     ServerAlias www.dizzydiz.com

     ProxyPass / http://10.10.10.18/
     # ProxyPassReverse / http://10.10.10.18/

     # Uncomment the line below if your site uses SSL.
     #SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the accepted answer on [this superuser.com question](https://superuser.com/questions/739736/apache-as-reverse-proxy-for-multiple-destinations-and-one-default-destination) I think it solves your problem.

In case that link is gone, have a look at the Apache page on [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#proxy).

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the sites

Type the following commands to activate, replace "example" with your .conf name.

sudo a2ensite example.com.conf

then do

sudo service apache2 restart

You may get a error message saying: 
 * Restarting web server apache2
 AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

This is fine, this will not effect your site.

Also follow this:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts